# Child components needing data from their own API

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have a parent component (representing the current URL) and three child components. Each component needs to do an API request to get the data it needs.

My initial solution was to subscribe in the parent to the route params and to then dispatch an action which is caught by three effects (one for each component) which will do the API calls and finally three reducers will store the responses.

Is this the best approach or is there a more suitable method?

Comment: Your solution sounds good. Also I would add that you want to handle all your subscriptions to the result to of the effects in the parent component and async pipe the results into @Inputs() on the child components. Also in your child components set the changeDetection to OnPush.

Comment: @runyards makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Comment: @runyards: One last thing, would you dispatch one action `parent.changed` which three effects would catch or rather dispatch three separate actions: `child1.load`, `child2.load` and `child3.load`

Comment: It really depends, one action seems less bulky compared to dispatching 3 separate ones, however keep in mind that later on down the line having separate ones give you more control as you might just want to update one of the components or reuse them somewhere else and might not need all 3 to fire off. If you want to use one action create a new one like loadAlll so you have a specif one for loading all of them and not just re-purpose the child1.load to all.